# How do pointers and nested structure work?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to pointers and nested structures. The code is below:

```
updateContact(struct Contact contacts[]);
getContacts(struct Contact* pContact);
getNumbers(struct Numbers* pNumbers);

#include <stdio.h>
struct Numbers
{
    int streetNumber;
};

struct Contact
{
    struct Numbers numbers;
};

int main()
{
    struct Contact contactArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    updateContact(contactArr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", contactArr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

updateContact(struct Contact contacts[])
{
    getContacts(&contacts);
}

getContacts(struct Contact* pContact)
{
    getNumbers(/*need help here*/);
        //what arguments should I pass so that the pointer pNumbers gets correct argument and updates the values  
}

getNumbers(struct Numbers* pNumbers)
{
    //update the values of all 4 elements to 5, 6, 7, 8
}
```

How is this data laid out in memory, if someone can help me imagine with the help of explanation, I am trying to think but cannot understand it properly, how does the program work from a pointer pointing a structure, to accessing the members of a nested structure that the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Have you tried to compile this? Getting something that can at least compile is the first step, before starting the thought exercise of how pointers work.

Comment: Yes it already works. I wanted to keep my solution as minimal as possible, otherwise the program is too long to post here.

Comment: It does not work. Copy and paste this code into a file and try to compile it.

Comment: The general rule is that the first member of a struct has the same address as the struct, and the addresses can be mutually cast to each other. That is, numerically &contact[0], &contact[0].numbers and &contact[0].numbers.streetNumber are all the same.

Comment: Updated the code snippet. @Z4-tier

Comment: @Soham: [this is what the compiler says](https://godbolt.org/z/YGhc9z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that you need to declare the structures before you can use them in the function prototypes. So move the prototypes to come *after* the structure definitions.

Next problem is that only `main` has a type. The rest of the functions are being defaulted to `int`. If the function doesn't return anything (like these), then declare it as `void`, both in the forward declaration and also the function definition itself.

Next is the series of function calls `updateContact` ---> `getContacts` ---> `getNumbers`. I think you are getting confused here with array syntax and pointers, but that can be cleared up pretty easily: they are the same thing. Let's take a look at what each argument looks like, starting at `main`:

```
    struct Contact contactArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    updateContact(contactArr);
```

What is `contactArr`? *It is an array of 4 `Contact` structures*. Another way to say that is *it is a pointer to the memory address of the first of 4 `Contact` structures*. When you call `updateContact`, it is receiving that memory address.

```
updateContact(struct Contact contacts[])
{
    getContacts(&contacts);
}
```

This is taking a `struct Contact contacts[]` as an argument.That can be written another way: `struct Contact* contacts`. Now it's taking a pointer. See what I meant when I said they are the same thing?

There is a problem here. `getContacts(&contacts)` doesn't do what you wanted. That is because `contacts` is *already a memory address*. If you do this, you're taking the address of an address. What good is that? remove the `&`, and pass it the memory address.

Ok, now the part you though was the problem:

```
getContacts(struct Contact* pContact)
{
    getNumbers(/*need help here*/);
        //what arguments should I pass so that the pointer pNumbers gets correct argument and updates the values  
}
```

It's taking `struct Contact* pContact`, but didn't we just see that? It's the same as `updateContact`, but written differently. So this is going to be the same value.

This last bit doesn't make complete sense to me:

```
getNumbers(struct Numbers* pNumbers)
{
    //update the values of all 4 elements to 5, 6, 7, 8
}
```

If you want to pass a `struct Numbers*` to this, you'll need to change `getContacts`. I think you meant this:

```
// Takes a pointer to a Contact type
void getContacts(struct Contact* pContacts) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
        getNumbers(&pContacts[n].numbers);
    }
}

// Takes a pointer to a Numbers type
void getNumbers(struct Numbers* pNumber) {
    static int val = 5;
    //update the values of all 4 elements to 5, 6, 7, 8
    pNumber->streetNumber = val++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have a follow up question to the solution you provided. In this line... getNumbers(&(pContacts[n]).numbers); what are you actually doing. So pContacts[n] has its own address. and numbers has its own address. So are you passing two addresses to the pointer of getNumbers? Or the address for pContact[n].numbers is tied to each other and is a same address. Is there something else that I'm missing. How is this data laid out in memory? @Z4-tier

Comment: @Soham that line is indexing to the `n`-th element of the `pContacts` array, accessing the member called `numbers`, and taking its address. I had added some confusing parenthesis in there that were not needed, so I edited it to remove those.

Comment: Thanks alot for your responses, it seems out of 64 people that read this threat, only you were the one to actually fix the issues, point them out and provide a complete explanation. Much appreciated. @Z4-tier